# C++: Including an external library in Makefile

Tags: makefile, g++, ldflags

So, I have some trouble including the ncurses-library in a C++ program. 
It seems my Makefile isn't set correctly and the library-functions can't be found. 
I installed the library with "sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev" and I'm able to compile my code manually via "g++ -o output src/main.cpp -lncurses".

The compiler settings in my `Makefile` looked like this:

```
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall`
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS = -lncurses
```

I'm using the "C/C++ Makefile Project" Plugin within Visual Studios Code on ubuntu.

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what the problem is.  _I have some trouble_ is not an issue we can address.

Comment: Hey, the lib-include didn't work, so i got an "undefined reference"-error to `initscr' and other curses-functions.
It's working now though with
LDFLAGS = -lncurses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As MadScientist explained, the second option follows the convention.

So, I found two solutions and I'm not sure which one or if any of them is the desired way of doing it:

1. Set LDFLAGS = -lncurses
2. Add $(LDLIBS) to a line in the Makefile:

```
# Builds the app
$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
   $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: You can do it however you want.  However if you want to follow _convention_, `LDFLAGS` should be used for linker options such as `-L`, while `LDLIBS` is used for libraries like `-lncurses`.  This is because in order for linking to work properly, libraries always must come _last_ on the link line while often linker options would come earlier.

Comment: Note well that `make` variables such as `LDLIBS` have no magical properties.  They are used only as specified by the rules in which they appear.  Some are a little special in that they appear in one or more of `make`'s implicit rules, but that's irrelevant as soon as you have an *explicit* rule applicable to building the desired target.